# iOS FBSDK FBSDKProfileExpressionSharer fails on very last step

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdk

In my image processing app I try to use Facebook Profile Expression Kit.
After calling method

```
[FBSDKProfileExpressionSharer uploadProfileVideoFromData:data metadata:nil];
```

my app opens Facebook, where I can crop length of video, select frame for static image. Everything looks good except very last step when I tap "Use" button. Facebook app starts upload video and then shows alert "Error Uploading Video".

[image: Error alert screenshot]

It might happen because app have to pass Facebook approve process. But it behaves the same when i tried it on test version of my App with Facebook test user.

Any ideas why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing "Profile Expression Kit" approved item for facebook developer app

1. Open https://developers.facebook.com/apps/%YOU_FB_APP_ID%/review-status/
2. Click "Start a Submission" button
3. Select Profile Expression Kit and add the item to your submission.
4. Fill in a note for review

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/review example review for messenger

Comment: You are right. That starts work well after passing review. It's strange behavior in my opinion. I expected that it should work well with test application id and test Facebook user.